# Cannot get result when row is fetched using model in codeigntier4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I try to get the row where email is as in the session variable using the following code in my controller.

```
 $usermodel = new \App\Models\UserModel();
      $user=$usermodel->where('email', $session->get('email'))->find();
```

I do not get the proper result. Instead of getting the row containing the email in session variable, I get an empty array as result. However when i try to get all the content using findAll without filtering using email, I get the result showing all content. How can I get a filtered result with the row containing the specified email in session variable.
I checked if the session variable contains value and it was found to have the correct value.

My model

```
<?php namespace App\Models;
use CodeIgniter\Database\ConnectionInterface;
use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_user';

    protected $allowedFields = ['name','email','password','image','role_id','isActive','date_created'];
}
```

Please help

I tried to get the row containing the email
But I get an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this by giving the where condition in find, i have not checked the code

```
      $usermodel = new \App\Models\UserModel();
      $user = $usermodel->find(['email'=> $session->get('email')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "first()" method if the email is unique.

```
  $user = $usermodel->where('email', session()->get('email'))->first()
```

Comment: I used xss_clean on the variable email before setting session and the email had html content like &commat; an &period and hence did not match the condition. When I removed the xss_clean before setting session varaiable, the condition matched and I got the result